# ionic popup close not working

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have created an ionic app where a popup window is opened to ask user to rate this app if he did not rate this app previously. Ionic popup appear correctly, but my problem is, user have to click/tap on cancel button twice to close popup and sometimes click/tap is not working.

My code is given below:

```
 (function() {

      $scope.data = {}

      var myPopup = $ionicPopup.show({
        template: '<input type="range" ng-model="data.user_ratting">',
        title: 'Do you want to rate this app?',
        scope: $scope,
        buttons: [
          { text: 'Cancel' },
          {
            text: '<b>Save</b>',
            type: 'button-positive',
            onTap: function(e) {

             }
          }
       ]
  });

    myPopup.then(function(res) {
      console.log('Tapped!', res);
    });

 })();
```

How can I solve this problem??

Comment: Where are you testing your app? Which version of the framework are you using?

Comment: I test my app on android emulator and ionic version is 1.6.4

Comment: Where does this $scope variable comes from? Is it intended to be a clean $scope (Hence the enclosing function() ?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you try  this one

```
var popup = $ionicPopup.show({
    title: 'Enter Wi-Fi Password',
    subTitle: 'Please use normal things',
    scope: $scope,
    buttons: [
              { text: 'ready',  onTap: function(e) {
                  console.log(e);
                  return true; 
                } 
           }
             ]
  }).then(function(result){
    console.log('Tapped', result);
  }, function(error){
    console.log('error', error);
  }, function(popup){
    popup.close();
  })
```

Comment: thanks for answer but when I try to show the popup in switch case its not working do know any solution for it

Comment: case 'false': $ionicPopup.show({ title: 'Invalid Passcode!', template: 'Please enter valid Passcode.', scope: $scope, buttons: [ { text: '<b>Ok</b>', type: 'button-positive', onTap: function(e) { } } ] }); for switch case its not working

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at the codepen I Did for you :

http://codepen.io/privetr/pen/QjjyMB

```
$scope.openPopup = function() {
  var myPopup = $ionicPopup.show({
    template: '<input type="range" ng-model="data.user_ratting">',
    title: 'Do you want to rate this app?',
    scope: $scope,
    buttons: [
      { text: 'Cancel' },
      {
        text: '<b>Save</b>',
        type: 'button-positive',
        onTap: function(e) {

         }
      }
   ]
});

myPopup.then(function(res) {
  console.log('Tapped!', res);
});
}

// To automatically open the popup
$scope.openPopup();
```

this code works, I just added a function to call the Popup when the top right button is clicked.

I hope it will solves your problem !

Comment: click event works, but I need to load popup automatically

Comment: Then, after the initialization of the function, call $scope.openPopup();
I added it to the codepen

Comment: thanks for answer but when I try to show the popup in switch case its not working do know any solution for it

Comment: case 'false':
                        $ionicPopup.show({
                            title: 'Invalid Passcode!',
                            template: 'Please enter valid Passcode.',
                            scope: $scope,
                                buttons: [
                                  {
                                      text: '<b>Ok</b>',
                                      type: 'button-positive',
                                      onTap: function(e) {     }
                                  }
                                ]
                        });